# Upload de multifiles com Multer , express , nodejs e query para Mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, express.js, multer

Como fazer a query do nome de duas imagens diferentes para mysql?

Estou a usar multer para fazer o upload de mais que uma imagem, e o código que utilizei está a funcionar perfeitamente. As imagens são carrregadas para a minha pasta `imgpost`. O meu problema é para fazer a query do nome de cada imagem para a minha database em mysql.

Aqui está o código utilizado:

```
    const path = require('path')
    const multer  = require('multer')

    const uploadImg = function (req, res) {
        
      let file_name = ''
      var values = [];

      const storage = multer.diskStorage({

          destination: path.join(__dirname, '../../public/imgpost/'),
          filename: function(req, file, cb){
            const uni = new Date().getTime();
            file_name = uni + '-' + file.originalname
            cb(null, uni + '-' + file.originalname);
          }

      });



      const upload = multer({
      storage: storage,
      fileFilter: function(req, file, cb){
          checkFileType(file, cb);
      }
      }).any();


    // Check File Type
      function checkFileType(file, cb){

        // Allowed ext
        const filetypes = /jpeg|jpg|png|gif/;
        // Check ext
        const extname = filetypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase());
        // Check mime
        const mimetype = filetypes.test(file.mimetype);
      
        if(mimetype && extname){
          return cb(null,true);
        } else {
          cb('Error: Images Only!');
        }

      }

      

      upload(req, res, (err) => {

        const titulo = req.body.titulo;
        const firstp = req.body.firstp;
        const categoria = req.body.categoria;
       
        
          if(err){

            console.log(err)

          } else {

            if(req.file == undefined){

              console.log('Error: No File Selected!')

            } else {

              values.push([titulo, firstp,  file_name,  categoria]);
              console.log(values)

              db.query('INSERT INTO posts (titulo, firtsp, first_image,  categoria) VALUES ?', [values], function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                  error = 'SQL ERROR ' + err.sqlMessage;
                }
                else {
                  error = 'Blog added successfully';
                }
                req.flash('success', error);
                res.redirect('/blogue');
              });
              
            }
          }
        })
    }

    module.exports = {
        uploadImg: uploadImg
    }
```

Com este código,se por exemplo carregar duas imagens o nome(`file_name`) da ultima imagem carregada é enviada para a minha tabela `first_image`, eu gostaria de saber como fazer enviar o nome da outra imagem para uma segunda tabela `second_image`. Alguém que possa ajudar?

Answer (score -1):

Descobri como o fazer! Obrigado na mesma e deixo aqui a solução para outros novatos como eu :

```js
const path = require('path')
const multer  = require('multer')

const uploadImg = function (req, res) {
    
  let file_name = ''
  
  var values = [];

  const storage = multer.diskStorage({

      destination: path.join(__dirname, '../../public/imgpost/'),
      filename: function(req, files, cb){
        const uni = new Date().getTime();
        file_name = uni + '-' + files.originalname
        cb(null, uni + '-' + files.originalname);
        
      }
  });


  const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  fileFilter: function(req, files, cb){
      checkFileType(files, cb);
  }
  }).fields([{ name: 'first_image', maxCount: 1 }, { name: 'second_image', maxCount: 1 }])


// Check File Type
  function checkFileType(files, cb){

    // Allowed ext
    const filetypes = /jpeg|jpg|png|gif/;
    // Check ext
    const extname = filetypes.test(path.extname(files.originalname).toLowerCase());
    // Check mime
    const mimetype = filetypes.test(files.mimetype);
  
    if(mimetype && extname){
      return cb(null,true);
    } else {
      cb('Error: Images Only!');
    }

  }

  upload(req, res, (err) => {

    const titulo = req.body.titulo;
    const firstp = req.body.firstp;
    const categoria = req.body.categoria;
    const image1 = req.files['first_image'][0].filename;
    let image2 = "";
    if(req.files['second_image']){
    image2 = req.files['second_image'][0].filename;
    }
    
      if(err){

        console.log(err)

      } else {

        if(req.files == undefined){

          console.log('Error: No File Selected!')
        

        } else {

          values.push([titulo, firstp,  image1, image2,  categoria]);
          console.log(values)

          db.query('INSERT INTO posts (titulo, firtsp, first_image, second_image, categoria) VALUES ?', [values], function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
              error = 'SQL ERROR ' + err.sqlMessage;
            }
            else {
              error = 'Blog added successfully';
            }
            req.flash('success', error);
            res.redirect('/blogue');
          });
          
        }
      }
    })
}

module.exports = {
    uploadImg: uploadImg
}
```